# Find all real solutions of $ \frac{ae^x}{2e^x-1} < 1 $

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, logarithms

> > Question: Find all real solutions of $ \frac{ae^x}{2e^x-1} < 1 $, where $a$ is a positive constant.

This is what I have attempted:

Consider $$ \frac{ae^x}{2e^x-1} < 1 $$

Case 1: $2e^x -1 > 0 $

Hence $$ \Leftrightarrow ae^x < 2e^x -1 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 1 < 2e^x - ae^x $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 2e^x - ae^x > 1 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow e^x(2-a) > 1 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow e^x > \frac{1}{2-a} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x > \ln\left( \frac{1}{2-a}\right)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x > \ln ( (2-a)^{-1} ) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x > -\ln(2-a) $$

Where $ 2-a > 0 \Leftrightarrow 2>a \Leftrightarrow a<2 $

But due to log domain restrictions $a$ cannot be less than zero therefore this solution only exists when $0<a<2$

Case 2: $2e^x -1 < 0$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 2e^x < 1 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow e^x < \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x < \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x < - \ln(2) $$

Therefore the solutions for this inequality is

$$ x < - \ln(2) ~~ \mathrm{and}~~x > -\ln(2-a)  $$

Where $0<a<2$

Am I correct?

Comment: If $x$ is large and negative, then the expression is approx 0 and hence $<1$ for any value of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct?

You are not correct. There are solutions for $a\ge 2$.

It seems that you don't understand the following :  $(ae^x)/(2e^x-1)\lt 1\iff$ "$2e^x-1\gt 0$ and $ae^x\lt 2e^x-1$" or "$2e^x-1\lt 0$ and $ae^x\gt 2e^x-1$". You got the right answer for $0\lt a\lt 2$ (though "and" has to be "or"), but the process looks strange especially in case 2 (you have to have not only $2e^x\lt 1$ but also $ae^x\gt 2e^x-1$.)

---

Case 1 :

Case 1-1 : For $0\lt a\lt 2$,
$$\begin{align}&2e^x-1\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad ae^x\lt 2e^x-1\\&\iff e^x\gt 1/2\quad\text{and}\quad (2-a)e^x\gt 1\\&\iff x\gt \ln(1/2)\quad\text{and}\quad e^x\gt 1/(2-a)\\&\iff x\gt -\ln 2\quad\text{and}\quad x\gt -\ln(2-a)\\&\iff x\gt -\ln (2-a)\end{align}$$

Case 1-2 : For $a\ge 2$,
$$\begin{align}&2e^x-1\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad ae^x\lt 2e^x-1\\&\iff e^x\gt 1/2\quad\text{and}\quad (2-a)e^x\gt 1\end{align}$$
There is no $x$ such that $(2-a)e^x\gt 1$.

Case 2 :

Case 2-1 : For $0\lt a\lt 2$,

$$\begin{align}&2e^x-1\lt 0\quad\text{and}\quad ae^x\gt 2e^x-1\\&\iff e^x\lt 1/2\quad\text{and}\quad (2-a)e^x\lt 1\\&\iff x\lt \ln(1/2)\quad\text{and}\quad e^x\lt 1/(2-a)\\&\iff x\lt -\ln 2\quad\text{and}\quad x\lt -\ln(2-a)\\&\iff x\lt -\ln 2\end{align}$$

Case 2-2 : For $a\ge 2$,

$$\begin{align}&2e^x-1\lt 0\quad\text{and}\quad ae^x\gt 2e^x-1\\&\iff x\lt -\ln 2\quad\text{and}\quad (2-a)e^x\lt 1\\&\iff x\lt -\ln 2\end{align}$$

Hence,

- For $0\lt a\lt 2$, the answer is $\color{red}{\text{$x\lt -\ln 2\ $ or $\ x\gt -\ln (2-a)$}}$.
- For $a\ge 2$, the answer is $\color{red}{x\lt -\ln 2}$.